# Alternative PnP commands to SharePoint Online Commands

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, pnp-powershell, pnp

Are there any alternative PnP commands to SharePoint Online Commands such as:

- Connect-SPOService
- Disconnect-SPOService
- Set-SPOUser
- Set-SPOSite
- Get-SPOSite
- Add-SPOSiteCollectionAppCatalog

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/overview?view=sharepoint-ps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see below, You can get the [complete list of PNP commands here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps)

- Connect-SPOService = [Connect-PnPOnline](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/connect-pnponline?view=sharepoint-ps)
- Disconnect-SPOService = [Disconnect-PnPOnline](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/disconnect-pnponline?view=sharepoint-ps)
- Set-SPOUser = nothing equal for it.
- Set-SPOSite = [Set-PnPSite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpsite?view=sharepoint-ps)
- Get-SPOSite = [Get-PnPSite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpsite?view=sharepoint-ps)
- Add-SPOSiteCollectionAppCatalog  = [Add-PnPSiteCollectionAppCatalog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnpsitecollectionappcatalog?view=sharepoint-ps)